# Como colocar botão ao lado de dois campos de texto

Tags: android

Estou querendo por o botão ao lado dos edit text, já fiz varias tentativas com layout_toleftof e layout weight mas o botão acaba sumindo, ou fica no mesmo lugar.
Meu xml ta assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="1234567890.,"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTextComercial"
    android:hint="Diametro Comercial"
    android:maxLines="1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="1234567890.,"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTextVC"
    android:hint="Velocidade de Corte"
    android:maxLines="1" />

<Button
    android:text="Calcular "
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonCalc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textViewResultRPM" />
```

[image: botão embaixo dos campos de texto]

Comment: Use LinearLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o que deseja é fazer da seguinte maneira:

[image: Layou img]

Tenho duas soluções, uma com Linear outro com relative layour, segue a do Linear, nele criei outros layouts dentro, um com orientação vertical para colocar os Edit text , e outro horizontal para separar esse layout dos Edit text com o do botão por weight.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:digits="1234567890.,"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editTextComercial"
            android:hint="Diametro Comercial"

            android:maxLines="1" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:digits="1234567890.,"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editTextVC"
            android:hint="Velocidade de Corte"
            android:maxLines="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:text="Calcular "
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/buttonCalc"
        android:layout_weight="2"

        />
</LinearLayout>




<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textViewResultRPM" />
```

No relative layout foi um pouco mais complicado, contudo a solução é mais simples, basta adicionar: `android:layout_toEndOf="@id/editTextComercial"
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/editTextVC"` para poder alinha o botão ao final do width e do bottom do Edit text , claro que deve ser adicionado um valor no width dos Edit text.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="1234567890.,"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTextComercial"
    android:hint="Diametro Comercial"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textViewResultRPM"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextVC"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="1234567890.,"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTextVC"
    android:hint="Velocidade de Corte"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextComercial"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Calcular "
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonCalc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/editTextComercial"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/editTextVC"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editTextComercial" />
```

Comment: funcionou, estava usando linear, mas n pensei nisso de criar varios linear um dentro do outro, preciso estudar mais xml. vlw

Comment: Qualquer coisa, estamos ai para ajudar